# Integral in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus

Let Ω be the solid bounded below by the half-cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and above by the spherical surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Use spherical coordinates to evaluate the integral

$\iiint_\Omega e^{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$ $dxdydz$

Ive been bashing against this, but to no avail, any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: First you need to determine the bounds on $\theta$, $\varphi$, and $\rho$. The hardest one is probably $\varphi$ - for that one, think about the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and what angle it makes with the positive $z$-axis.

Comment: Ok so when ive been looking at this I have come to think the bounds are: $0\leq \rho\leq 1$, $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$, $0\leq \phi\leq \pi/4$ but the HALF cone, this confuses me a little, like you implied, Im mor doubtful of my $\phi$ bounds

Comment: I think the "half" just means it's half of the "double" cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$, which extends above and below the $xy$-plane (see here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%5E2%3Dx%5E2%2By%5E2). Your bounds look correct to me. Now you need to do a variable substitution and remember the integration factor for spherical coordinates.

Comment: By the way, in Brightsun's response below the variables $\theta$ and $\varphi$ are reversed from what they usually are. Your ranges for the variables are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spherical coordinates:
$$
x = r \sin\theta \cos\varphi\\
y = r \sin\theta \sin\varphi\\
z = r \cos\theta.
$$
The volume element:
$$
dxdydz = dr\, rd\theta\, r\sin\theta d\varphi.
$$
Since there is axial symmetry around the zeta axis, the domain of integration is independent of $\varphi$, the $\theta$ coordinate is restricted by the angle of the cone, whose half opening is $\pi/4$, and finally $r$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ since $\Omega$ is enclosed in the unit sphere; therefore:
$$
\iiint_\Omega e^{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}dx dy dz = 
\int_0^{2\pi} d\varphi \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^1 dr e^{r^3}r^2\\
=2\pi \left( 1- \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right)\frac{1}{3}\left(e-1\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Clovers you are welcome!