# Volume bounded by a half-cone and a spherical surface

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble computing the integral below. If someone could explain, with precise details, the method for obtaining an answer so I can successfully solve similar problems in the future, it would be greatly appreciated.

Let $\Omega$ be the solid bounded below by the half-cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and above by the spherical surface $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Use spherical coordinates to evaluate the integral

$$\iiint\limits_{\Omega} e^{({x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}^{3/2}}\, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z.$$

Comment: Did you mean: $\int\int\int e^{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\, dxdydz$?

Comment: Also, your half-cone equation has a box in it, I can't tell what it is.

Comment: I believe you meant: $$\Omega = \left\{u\in \mathbb{R}_+^3 :  u_3^2 \geq u_1^2 + u_2^2 , ||u|| \leq 1 \right\}$$ and $$\int_\Omega e^{||u||^3}du.$$
Right?

Comment: Yes, that's the integral, mea culpa. & yes, I think that's Ω, although it hasn't been specified.

Comment: You might be interested in this post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570132/integral-in-spherical-coordinates/1570151?noredirect=1#comment3196461_1570151

Comment: Start by working out where the two bounding surfaces (the sphere, the half-cone) meet.  In this case the intersection is fairly simple, and may suggest a nice way to decompose the volume $\Omega$ that they bound.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to determine the spherical equation of the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$. Substituting $x,y,z$ by $\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta), \rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta),\rho\cos(\phi)$ respectively, yields:

$$
\rho^2 \cos^2(\phi)=\rho^2 \sin^2(\phi),
$$
and there is only one angle that satisfies this equation in $[0,\pi]$: $\pi/4$. Therefore, in spherical coordinates, the half cone has equation $\phi=\frac{\pi}{4}$. It is trivial that the sphere has equation $\rho=1$. Therefore you can write $\Omega$ as

$$
\Omega=\{(\rho,\theta,\phi)\;|\; 0\le \theta \le 2\pi, 0\le \rho\le 1, 0\le \phi\le \frac{\pi}{4} \},
$$

and it follows that your integral equals
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^1 e^{\rho^3}\rho^2\sin(\phi) d\rho d\phi d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{2}-2}{3}(1-e)\pi.
$$

The general method for these integrals consists in looking at a projection of $\Omega$ in the 2D plane. In spherical coordinates, you will want to look at $\Omega$ in the $yz$ plane. It will give you 
$$
D=\{(\rho,\phi)\;|\;  0\le \rho\le 1, 0\le \phi\le \frac{\pi}{4}  \}.
$$
And now to generate $\Omega$, you have to pivot $D$ by 360°, hence the description of $\Omega$ above. Ask yourself this question: if you had to answer the question in cylindrical coordinates, in what plane would you project $\Omega$? The answer is the $xy$ plane…do you see why? Another aspect when solving these integrals is looking at the function inside the integral. The $x^2+y^2+z^2$ hints to you that spherical coordinates are appropriate.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for providing the method with extensive explanation- would you be able to recommend any further reading on the subject? I've a January exam on multivariable functions and would love to be able to familiarise myself more in depth with them before that time. Additionally, could you explain how ϕ=${π/4}$? (potentially graphically). & also, where does the $p^2$sin(ϕ) come from with your integral?

Comment: I'v edited the post with further explanations. The $\rho^2\sin(\phi)$ plays the same role as the extra $r$ in polar coordinates ($rdrd\theta$). You need these extra terms otherwise $drd\theta$ and $d\theta d\rho d\phi$ are not small surfaces or volumes (respectively). I think you may need to read your textbook carefully; it should be well explained.